# Notation for a sequence of points

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to say a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which of the following ways of writing is correct?
\begin{equation}
        \{p_n \in \mathbb{R}^3\}_{n=1}^{\infty}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
        \{p_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathbb{R}^3
\end{equation}

Comment: $\{p_n\} \subset \mathbb  R^{3}$.

Comment: "Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$" is quite clear. Why use symbols when words are better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedantically, a sequence $(p_n)$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a function $p: \mathbb N \to \mathbb{R}^3$, but almost no one writes a sequence like this.

A notation like $\{p_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ suggests the *set* that is the image of the sequence, not the sequence itself.

Why use symbols when words are better? The sentence below is quite clear.

> Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.